# Testfor PHP $_GET value using if statement

Tags: php, get

I want to testfor the value of a GET variable using an if statement. Here is the code I have:

```
if(isset($_GET["v"]) == "test1") {
echo 'It worked: test1 loaded';
}

if(isset($_GET["v"]) == "test2") {
echo 'It worked: test2 loaded';
}
```

and my url is https://www.example.com/video?v=test1

I want to be able to change the content that loads on page depending on the info in the url. Similar to how YouTube videos are all on the same "watch" file, but have a $_Get query afterwords that defines which video to load:
www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNZLhuW8vk

But it doesn't work, so I'm assuming that my if statement is messed up.

Comment: you need to break those up into 2 seperate conditions.

Comment: Like this:
if(isset($_GET["v"])) {
if($v  == "test1") {
echo 'It worked: test1 loaded'; }
}

Comment: To expand on the above comment, `isset` returns a boolean indicating whether the property is set. It doesn't make sense to compare that to a string value.

Comment: @NathanMartin your `if($v == "test1")` would only throw an undefined variable notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset()` returns `true` or `false` which does not equal to "test1", to get the desired behaviour you need to evaluate the actual value of `$_GET['v']` like this:

```
if(isset($_GET["v"]) && $_GET['v'] == "test1") {
    echo 'It worked: test1 loaded';
}

if(isset($_GET["v"]) && $_GET['v'] == "test2") {
    echo 'It worked: test2 loaded';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Break up your conditionals into 2 seperate conditions, since what you have now will always be considered as being set.

The following is interpreted as: if set and equal to:

I.e.:

```
if(isset($_GET["v"]) && $_GET["v"] == "x")
```

The "x" being a representative value of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET["v"]) && $_GET['v'] == "test1") {
    echo 'It worked: test1 loaded';
}
else if(isset($_GET["v"]) && $_GET['v'] == "test2") {
    echo 'It worked: test2 loaded';
}
```

Or use switch when there are too much options

```
if(isset($_GET["v"]))
{
    switch($_GET["v"])
    {
        case "test1":
        echo 'It worked: test1 loaded';
        break;
        case "test2":
        echo 'It worked: test2 loaded';
        default:
        echo 'Not Recognized';
        break;
    }
} 

if(isset($_GET["v"]) == "test1")
```

Your Expression is wrong because  `isset()`  return a boolean value and later you are testing against a string
 `if(bool == string)`  is always false